# Rust waiting for Tokio threads to finish

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm trying to create a little program that will kick off new threads whenever an MPSC channel receives a message. I'm able to get the program to kick off the threads, but can't figure out how to get to the program to stay open.

Here is the app:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let (sender, mut receiver) = mpsc::channel(100);

    let handles = Arc::new(tokio::sync::Mutex::new(vec![]));
    let handles_clone = handles.clone();
    let consumer_task = tokio::spawn(async move {
        while let Some(item) = receiver.recv().await {
            println!("Consumer received: {}", item);
            let h = tokio::spawn(async move {
                println!("Thread {} working", item);
                sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
                println!("Thread {} done", item);
            });
            {
                let mut handles = handles_clone.lock().await;
                handles.push(h);
            }
        }
    });

    let producer_task = tokio::spawn(async move {
        for i in 0..5 {
            let _ = sender.send(i).await;
        }
    });

    let mut handles = handles.lock().await;
    handles.push(consumer_task);
    handles.push(producer_task);

    let a = handles.deref();

    join_all(a);
```

My thought is that I need to join_all on the handles that I'm kicking off, but am having trouble figuring out how I can push handles onto the vector inside the receiver thread, AND then join_all at the end of the program to block until those threads are done.

I wrapping the handles vec in an Arc<Mutex<_>> since I want to reference the handles vec inside the receiver thread, but I can't seem to join_all at the end, and get this error:

```
`&tokio::task::JoinHandle<()>` is not a future
the trait `futures::Future` is not implemented for `&tokio::task::JoinHandle<()>`
&tokio::task::JoinHandle<()> must be a future or must implement `IntoFuture` to be awaited
the trait `futures::Future` is implemented for `tokio::task::JoinHandle<T>`
`futures::Future` is implemented for `&mut tokio::task::JoinHandle<()>`, but not for `&tokio::task::JoinHandle<()>`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see that `&` in the error message? The compiler error comes from the fact you don't own the `JoinHandle`s when you call `join_all` (`JoinHandle`s can only be joined once, and thus they need to be owned to do that.) You can fix that error by replacing the last two lines with:

```rust
join_all(handles.drain(..)).await;
```

but then you race into a deadlock: The consumer task will try to lock `handles_clone`, but that is locked by the "main" task, waiting in `join_all`, which will never finish. You could circumvent this problem by locking, popping handles, and awaiting one by one, but you'd essentially have implemented an inefficient (lifo) channel by doing so. It would be better to actually use a channel, then.

Better yet, though, to make your life easier by moving the `handles` `Vec` into your consumer task and joining there. That makes the mutex unnecessary.

```rust
let (sender, mut receiver) = mpsc::channel(100);

let consumer_task = tokio::spawn(async move {
    let mut handles = vec![];
    while let Some(item) = receiver.recv().await {
        println!("Consumer received: {}", item);
        let h = tokio::spawn(async move {
            println!("Thread {} working", item);
            sleep(Duration::from_secs(2)).await;
            println!("Thread {} done", item);
        });

        handles.push(h);
    }
    join_all(handles).await;
});

let producer_task = tokio::spawn(async move {
    for i in 0..5 {
        let _ = sender.send(i).await;
    }
});

consumer_task.await.unwrap();
producer_task.await.unwrap();
```

Comment: What does use  for  mpsc::channel(100) , we can also use mpsc::channel() instead

Comment: @SamsulIslam I'm not able to decipher your English. Are you maybe interested in an [`unbounded_channel`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/mpsc/fn.unbounded_channel.html)? (Because no, you can't use `mpsc::channel()` without arguments.) In any case, this is pretty much unrelated to this question.